# Help Text not appearing when using apex:outputField with a custom label

Tags: visualforce, helptext

I am trying to add a custom label to an `apex:outputField` tag but when I do the help text disappears. How do I change the label but keep the help text?

The VF snippet below displays the same field three different ways. The first two uses a custom label and the third is the normal `apex:outputField` which will use the label from the SObject field. The output is shown below the code.

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Balances" columns="1">

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="My Label"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!sob.Balance__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:outputField value="{!sob.Balance__c}" label="My Label"/>

        <apex:outputField value="{!sob.Balance__c}"/> 

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Here is the output. The help text only appears on the third field.

[image: HelpText]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is easy. Just use the `helpText` attribute of the `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` and put the help info from the field in it:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Street__c.InlineHelpText}">
    <apex:outputLabel value="My Label"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!a.Street__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm

This is not a bug and works as designed and discussed in above document .

> Note that if you include an `<apex:outputField>` or an `<apex:inputField>` component in an `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`, these components do not display with their label or custom help text as they do when they are children of an `<apex:pageBlockSection>`. Also note that `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` components can't be rerendered; rerender the child components instead.

Comment: Does the same hold true for `<apex:outputField value="{!sob.Balance__c}" label="My Label"/>`?

Comment: Yes i observed the same behaviour .I think mast0r has right work around